# A uniform 6-regular graph consisting of triangles and quadrilaterals

Tags: graph-theory, mathematical-modeling, tiling

I am interested in a special uniform graph that can be constructed by attaching succesively three triangles to each other such that always four of them form a circle. (The nodes of my graph are the points where the triangles meet.)

Its motivation is a simplified friendship graph: consider a group of people of which each has six friends, which are half-pairwise friends to each other.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The graph (when extended to infinity) is $6$-regular and each node has exactly 21 neighbours at graph distance $2$. I guess it's not the only one that has this property, but assumably it is the most regular one (in fact it is completely symmetric, isn't it?) In a sense it's also the most "clustered".

My question is threefold:

- Has someone seen this graph in its whole fractal beauty?
- Under what name is this graph known?
- How do I calculate the adjacency matrix of this graph (i.e. a finite portion of it)?

Something like $a_{ij} = 1$ iff $\Phi(i,j)$ with an explicit expression $\Phi(i,j)$ would be welcome.

Comment: It's a uniform tiling of the hyperbolic plane, with vertex configuration 3.4.3.4.3.4 . [A picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Uniform_tiling_444-snub.png)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis: Thanks for the hint. Do you know a (online-)tool where I can enter vertex configurations and see how they look like?

Comment: You could take a look at [Tegula](https://www.wsi.uni-tuebingen.de/lehrstuehle/algorithms-in-bioinformatics/software/tegula) but I have not used it myself.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis. Thanks for the link. Please have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your graph can be nicely embedded in the hyperbolic plane as the [alternated octagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternated_octagonal_tiling), with three triangles and three squares meeting at each vertex.

(Why "octagonal"? Because, as a graph, it is the [half-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_half) of the [octagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octagonal_tiling) where three octagons meet at each vertex. To put it differently: starting from the octagonal tiling, if you replace every other vertex by a triangle, and grow these triangles until their corners touch, you get the alternated octagonal tiling.)

As far as seeing it in its whole fractal beauty, there's M.C. Escher's [Circle Limit III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Limit_III):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you possibly give me a hint how to calculate the adjacency matrix of this graph (i.e. a finite portion of it)? Something like $a_{ij} = 1$ iff $\Phi(i,j)$ for some expression $\Phi(i,j)$? (I'm stuck.)

Comment: Our first obstacle there is encoding the vertices of the graph in a nice way, and that's hard. I think they correspond to elements of a corresponding [triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group), and I think the right triangle group is $(2,3,8)$ because we can get from there to the [order-8 triangular tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-8_triangular_tiling), which is the dual of the octagonal tiling from which we get the alternated octagonal tiling. I don't know enough to fill in the gaps there.

Comment: In particular, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bwDN.png) is a picture of how we can construct your graph from the fundamental triangles of the $(2,3,8)$ triangle group.

Comment: Hi Misha, maybe you want to have a look at my answer which I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

[Tegula](https://www.wsi.uni-tuebingen.de/lehrstuehle/algorithms-in-bioinformatics/software/tegula) (thanks to user Jaap!) gave me this tiling:

[image]

It's the first when you filter by `geometry = hyperbolic` and `vertex degree = 6` and the second when you filter by `number of non-equivalent tiles = 2`, `number of non-equivalent edges = 1`, `number of non-equivalent vertices = 1`.

*[Side question: How does Tegula's nomenclature `n:3 t:2 e:1 v:1 g:*433` relate to the vertex configuration `3.4.3.4.3.4`? What especially does `n:3` mean?]*

Comment: n:3 is the "Dress complexity" of the tiling, in this case 3.
This is the number of elements in the "Delaney-Dress symbols" that represents the tiling... It is a measure of how complex the tiling is. t e and v refer to the number of non-equivalent tiles, edges and vertices.
*3222 is the orbifold notation for the symmetry group. The star represents reflections, while the different digits represent different rotation degrees...
This presentation might help with familiarizing yourself with these concepts: https://software-ab.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/download/tegula/Galaxy-of-tilings-2020.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Up to a not too large diameter the tritetragonal tiling can be quite easily drawn in the Euclidean plane and gives an idea of its fractal nature. What's more important: It allows to count vertices at distance 3 and 4, and all in all: to better understand and analyze the graph visually, at least locally:

[image]

By the way, I have an adjacency matrix for this particular graph, and I have an idea how to get it for even larger diameters (step by step, not in general).

This is another – less geometrical, more graphical – view of the graph, its shape depending on the order in which the nodes were created:

[image]

For the sake of completeness the same with smaller diameter:

[image] [image]